# SQL Server split comma into table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, algorithm

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following code:

```
declare @listOfIDs table (id int);
insert @listOfIDs(id) values(39572),(39793);
```

I want to do something like this to do the same result:

```
declare @listOfIDs table (id int);
insert @listOfIDs(id) split('39572,39793');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your split function is a table function, then you should have your insert statement as follows.

```
Insert @listofIDs(id)
Select * From split('39572,39793');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many Split/Parsing functions out there.

Here is one

```
declare @listOfIDs table (id int);
insert @listOfIDs(id) Select Key_Value from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('39572,39793',',')

Select * from @listOfIDs
```

Returns

```
id
39572
39793
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

> **Edit**

FYI if you just run

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('39572,39793',',')
```

It returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       39572
2       39793
```

I've found the Sequence Number (Key_PS) to be valuable at times.